# my insert command not changing the database when using through programming

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

When I am inserting values with query database is inserting when doing it with coding it won't insert although it show successful. Im using C# 2010 and 2012 Both are not adding
My Code

```
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Main_2(Name,NIC,NA_ID,PS_ID) values('" + name + "','" + nic + "',(SELECT NA_ID FROM NationalAssembly WHERE Name='" + na_name + "'),(SELECT PS_ID FROM ProvisionalAssembly Where Name='" + ps_name + "'))", con);
cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE ProvisionalAssembly SET Count=+1 WHERE Name='" + ps_name + "'", con);
cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE NationalAssembly SET Count=+1 WHERE Name='" + na_name + "'", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SqlCommand` is a *class*, that means it is a *reference types*.

Everytime you create a new `SqlCommand` object and you assing it `cmd` as a reference. That means only your last `SqlCommand` executes. Your first two `SqlCommand` doesn't have a reference anymore in memory when you execute with `ExecuteNonQuery` method.

If you want to execute all these commands, you need to execute separately for each command.

And please use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections.

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(YourInsertStatement))
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = YourFirstUpdateStatement;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = YourSecondUpdateStatement;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Excellent, well-formed response with good best practices info.  OP should accept this as the answer.